# Spring Content-Negotiation with Path Extension (set Accept-Header via extension?!)

Tags: json, spring, spring-mvc, content-negotiation

I want to have the same URL Path handles by two different @Controller methods, which partially works. Here's what I've got:

**WebMvcConfig:**

```
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {
    @Override
    protected void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter json = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
        json.setObjectMapper(objectMapper());
        converters.add(json);
        VCardMessageConverter vcard = new VCardMessageConverter();
        converters.add(vcard);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.favorPathExtension(true)
            .mediaType("json",  MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .mediaType("vcf",   MediaType.TEXT_VCARD)
            ;
    }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("test")
class UserProfileController {
    @RequestMapping(value="profile", method=RequestMethod.GET, produces=MediaType.TEXT_VCARD_VALUE)
    VCard getProfileVCard() {
        Profile p = service.getProfile();
        VCard v = p.getVCard();
        return v;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="profile", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    Profile getProfile() {
        Profile p = service.getProfile();
        return p;
    }
}
```

### Current behavior:

**The good ones:**

`GET /test/profile` (with `Accept=*/*`) calls `getProfile()`

`GET /test/profile` (with `Accept=application/json`) calls `getProfile()`

`GET /test/profile.json` (with `Accept=*/*`) calls `getProfile()`

`GET /test/profile.json` (with `Accept=text/vcard`) returns `406 NOT ACCEPTABLE`

`GET /test/profile` (with `Accept=text/vcard`) calls `getProfileVCard()`

`GET /test/profile.vcf` (with `Accept=text/vcard`) calls `getProfileVCard()`

**The faulty one:**

`GET /test/profile.vcf` (with `Accept=*/*`) calls `getProfile()` and returns `406 NOT ACCEPTABLE`.

Why does the wrong method get called? I thought I set `favorPathExtension(true)` in my config in order to make Spring override the Accept-Header when some Path Extension is set?

### EDIT:

I now also set `favorPathExtension(true).ignoreAcceptHeader(true).favorParameter(true)` in my config and it still doesn't work, even `profile?format=vcf` and `profile.vcf?format=vcf` don't work

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem?